# Добавить строку в QTableWidget если ее еще нет

Tags: c++, qt

Моя программа должна постепенно выводить результаты вычислений в ячейки таблицы.  Есть окно (реализовано как объект класса Widget, наследованного от QWidget), у этого объекта есть свойство r_table (указатель на QTableWidget) - эта самая таблица.

Сколько строк понадобится, заранее неизвестно, поэтому я хочу чтобы они добавлялись по мере необходимости.

Нужен метод

```
void Widget::setTableValue(int i, int j, double value)
```

который ставит число *value* в ячейку с номером строки *i* и номером столбца *j*, а если строки *i* нет, то создает ее.

Как такое реализовать?

Попытался сделать вот так

```
void Widget::setTableValue(int i, int j, double value)
{
    while (r_table->rowCount() < i)
        r_table->insertRow(r_table->rowCount());
    r_table->setItem(i, j, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(value, 'g', 2)));
}
```

но он заполняет таблицу как попало.

Comment: if (r_table->rowCount()<=i)r_table->setColCount(i+1);

Comment: может быть setRowCount?

Comment: не по теме, но всё же... `QTableWidget` — это игрушка... для любой задачи сложнее самого примитивного отображения нескольких строчек в таблице, ИМХО лучше использовать нормальную модель с `QTableView`... но это потребует некоторого времени на изучение фреймворка и отказа от вредных привычек...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это будет из пушки по воробьям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
void Widget::setTableValue(int i, int j, double value)
{
    if (r_table->rowCount() <= i)
        r_table->setRowCount(i + 1);
    r_table->setItem(i, j, new QTableWidgetItem(localeRus->toString(value, 'g', 4)));
}
```

localeRus - объект QLocale с русской локалью, чтобы десятичный разделитель был запятая.

Comment: хорошей практикой было бы использовать `QLocale::system()` вместо того, чтобы прибивать гвоздями к русской локали...